# Upload video from android to .net server using soap

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-video-player

I am a newbie want help me in uploading a video from my android phone. I have already done a lot of search on google but it was not fruitful. I want to upload to a .net web service which will be based on a soap service. Any input in this regard will be helpful. most of the people are saying to use multipart but this is my limitation that I have to use soap. Video length could be short like half a minute one.

I am giving below the code what I have tried till now.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

// directory name to store captured images and videos
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView videoPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
    btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

    /*
     * Capture image button click event
     */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // capture picture
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    /*
     * Record video button click event
     */
    btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // record video
            recordVideo();
        }
    });

    // Checking camera availability
    if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 * */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/*
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/*
 * Recording video
 */
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // video successfully recorded
            // preview the recorded video
            previewVideo();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // hide video preview
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Previewing recorded video
 */
private void previewVideo() {
    try {
        // hide image preview
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());

        Log.i("Vid File", fileUri.getPath());

        // start playing
        videoPreview.start();

        UpVidClass upVidClass = new UpVidClass();
        upVidClass.execute(fileUri.getPath());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

/*
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/*
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class UpVidClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String path = params[0];

        try {
            uploadVideo(path);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) throws ParseException,
            IOException {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ccrbest.com/cse/log/");

        FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
        StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: vid"); // + videoPath);
        StringBody description = new StringBody(
                "This is a description of the video");

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
        reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
        reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        } // end if

        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        } // end if

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } // end of uploadVideo( )

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit this question accordingly. Only then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I have posted a complete activity code so that if anyone tries to compile it will be quickly done.